# DISTINCT on only a few columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, greatest-n-per-group

[image]

In the above image, is it possible to run a DISTINCT on name2 and name whilst still returning all 3 columns?

Example above with expected output returning row 2 and row 3. Assuming I can select MAX on id.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: any ideas with Spark SQL?

Comment: got it, drop duplicates! Thanks for sparking the thought